# Convert this SQL query into JPA CriteriaBuilder query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I want to convert this query using CriteriaBuilder library:

**Query:**

```
SELECT e.id as employeeId, addr.id as addressId FROM
        employee e
        INNER JOIN
        address addr on e.id = addr.employee_id
        WHERE
        e.name = 'juan' AND e.lastName = 'perez'
        AND
        '2022-03-21' = addr.createdDate
        order by
        e.createdDate desc
```

**Entities:**

```
 class Employee {
            
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String lastName;
        private String createdDate;
        
         // getters and setters 
            
        }
    
    
    class Address {
        
    private int id;
    private int employee_id;
    private String createdDate; 
    
     // getters and setters 
        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. To help you to convert your SQL query into HQL query you must add in your question the classes (Employee, Address)

Comment: I added the entities i am using